# Binomial theorem and logarithms

Tags: logarithms, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, arithmetic-progressions

Let $n$ be a positive integer, such that the coefficients of the fifth, sixth and seventh terms, with respect to $x$, of the development of $\bigg (\frac {log_n (\sqrt {2 ^ n})} {log_e (n) .log_n (\sqrt {2 ^ e)}} + x \bigg) ^ n$ according to the decreasing powers of $x$, they are in arithmetic progression. Determine $n$.

We have that $n\geq6$

Using the infomation given, I wrote
$2\binom{n}{5}\cdot\bigg(\frac{n\log_ne}{e}\bigg)^5=\binom{n}{4}\cdot\bigg(\frac{n\log_ne}{e}\bigg)^4+\binom{n}{6}\cdot\bigg(\frac{n\log_ne}{e}\bigg)^6$

Simplifying this, I got
$n^2(n-4)(n-5)\log_ne-6n(n-4)e\log_ne+3e=0$

I don't know what I have to do now :/

Can someone help me?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Are you sure your simplified result is correct? I'm getting something else.

Comment: I did 3 times, but I can confused something. Can you post your result?

Comment: Much different than that.

Comment: But Wolfram gives n=2 or 3. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2binomial%28n%2C+5%29%28n%2F%28eln%28n%29%29%29%5E5%3Dbinomial+%28n%2C+4%29%28n%2F%28eln%28n%29%29%29%5E4%2Bbinomial+%28n%2C+6%29%28n%2F%28eln%28n%29%29%29%5E6

Comment: So this problem doesn't have solution

Comment: Thanks @UmbQbify

Comment: My edit was only for the typo "logarithimis" in the title. It would make more sense to spell it "logarithims" but John Napier, who discovered (invented?) them in the 1500's chose "logarithms".